# Running aapt on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, aapt

I downloaded the Android Open Source Project and built it on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit) using the instructions here:

http://source.android.com/source/building.html

I can get it to build without a problem.  When the build is done, I'm interested in the build tools, particularly aapt.  When I run it, I see this:

```
awt@aosp-build:/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk/android-sdk_eng.awt_linux-x86/build-tools/android-5.0.50.50.50.50$ ./aapt
./aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So, that's strange.  Especially considering that libc++.so is right there in the same directory:

```
awt@aosp-build:/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/sdk/sdk/android-sdk_eng.awt_linux-x86/build-tools/android-5.0.50.50.50.50$ ls -l

-rwxrwxr-x 1 awt awt 1118633 Feb  4 19:42 aapt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 awt awt 1261036 Feb  4 19:42 libc++.so

$ file aapt
aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped
$ file libc++.so 
libc++.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

I've built and used older Android versions of build-tools, the last one was 4.3.  To get that one to run, I needed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

That allowed me to run it and it worked.  With the latest from Android, this is no longer enough.  I still get the `libc++.so: cannot open shared object file message`.

There are other intermediate versions of aapt in the out directory.  For example, this one:

$ file /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt 
aapt: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, not stripped
$ ls -l /aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 awt awt 6978260 Feb  4 17:50 aapt

This one runs.  It hasn't been stripped yet so the shared libs are still embedded in it.  If I strip it:

```
$ strip -s aapt
$ ./aapt
./aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then we're back to where we started.  What can I do to to make the stripped version run the way it used to?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question but a recent upvote on it reminded me that I do have a solution.

The answer is to append the location of libc++.so to the current LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/path/to/libc++.so
$ ./aapt -version
Android Asset Packaging Tool

Usage:
   aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
   List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
```